# Can i use <> with outer join?

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT `employee`.`fname` 
FROM `employee` 
OUTER JOIN `test` ON `employee`.`id`=`test`.`id` 
WHERE `test`.`lname` <> null;
```

it is giving syntax error.

WHY?

Answer (score 1):

`OUTER` is optional in `LEFT OUTER JOIN`, not `LEFT`

```
SELECT `employee`.`fname` 
FROM `employee` 
LEFT OUTER JOIN `test` ON `employee`.`id`=`test`.`id` 
WHERE `test`.`lname` is not null;
```

And to check for `null` use the `is` operator.

BTW you can remove the `is not null` check if you use an `inner join`.

Answer (score 1):

if you have to check that a column is not  null so you have to  `is not null` not `<>`

```
SELECT `employee`.`fname` FROM `employee` OUTER JOIN `test` ON `employee`.`id`=`test`.`id` WHERE `test`.`lname` is not null;
```